# Accessing a JSON object that contains a nested array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I made an API call (google translate) and it returns the following:

```
{
 "data": {
  "detections": [
   [
    {
     "language": "en",
     "isReliable": false,
     "confidence": 0.051902372
    }
   ]
  ]
 }
}
```

I want to access the "language" value using javascript (using the jQuery ajax function).  I tried something like:

```
response.data.detections[0][0].language
```

but that does not work.  Help?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? If the variable `response` is set to that data structure, `response.data.detections[0][0].language` returns `"en"`

Comment: It works for me, if i access it in the format you have provided.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EfJBN/ works for me

Answer (score 1):

We really do need more information but if I had to guess blindly I would guess that response actually contains the following string:

```
'{
 "data": {
  "detections": [
   [
    {
     "language": "en",
     "isReliable": false,
     "confidence": 0.051902372
    }
   ]
  ]
 }
}'
```

If that is the case you could try something like $.parseJSON(response).data.detections[0][0].language